# Changing order of fields in Drupal's content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-templates

I am using Drigg on Drupal 6.17. Drigg has a content type called as "Scoop". I try to change the labels and order of fields. Normally, this is done in `Content Management > Content Types > Manage Fields` . But some fields that are shown in `Create Content` screen are not shown in `Manage Fields` screen.

The screenshot of `Manage Fields` is here:

[image]

The screenshot of `Create Content` view is here:

[image]

The first three fields (`Submit the scoop as.., Scoop's URL, Scoop`) in `Create Content` form are not shown in `Manage Fields` view.

I would like to ask the reason for this. They must be defined somewhere else. Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage fields is for editing CCK fields that you have added. Other fields from different modules often have a weight setting that you can change to move the field up and down, which you would get to from the main content type editing page.

Comment: Thank you. Then these three initial fields are added outside of CCK. They might have a weight setting but its existence and place depends on the module which added those fields.